# Clearing TableLayout inside LinearLayout removes TextView Header

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I have a LinearLayout with a TextView and TableLayout embedded in it. here is the format of my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
 >
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Header"  />
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
     <TableRow>
      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/row1Item1"
         android:text="Column1" />
       <!-- Column 2 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/row1Item2"
         android:text="Column2" />
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding rows dynamically to the table. Everytime, I get an update, I need to clear the table and write new information (number of rows are variables). So, I am trying to do clear the table as a first step whenever I have to update.

```
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.wlayout);
    tb = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.wtable);

private void on Update(){
tb.removeAllViewsInLayout();

Create table dynamically..
}
```

But it is removing my text header also. I have also tried ll.removeView(tb) where ll is the LinearLayout. Can any one please help me. I am new to Android. Thank you.

Comment: Understood what i mean to say ??

Answer (score 0):

You have not given id to TableLayout tag.Please give id and then try to clear it.

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="+@id/wtable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
     <TableRow>
      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/row1Item1"
         android:text="Column1" />
       <!-- Column 2 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/row1Item2"
         android:text="Column2" />
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And then try this..

```
tb = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.wtable);  
tb.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

Comment: Oh I am so sorry..I did give a id to my table. I was just trying to show the format of my xml..So I removed it temporarily here.

Comment: the header row is also getting deleted.is there any way to keep the header and delete the dynamically created rows